# Adding Reference for livsvm in Visual Studio 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, libsvm

I am new in using `livsvm`, i want to use it in coding level, that is i have to add reference in `c#`. I tired but the ain't succeed with the  error messages as shown with the attached image. Please help me to use `livsvm` library in c#, **any significant steps to add reference.**

[image: Error Message]

Comment: FYI, Visual Studio 8 is Visual Studio 2005, not Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I am almost sure that your are using a library version incompatible with you current .NET framework version. Have you checked that?

Comment: I know, the compatible version for .NET is SVM.NET. Finally problem solved with SVM.dll.